# how do I setup XMR-STAK-AMD webservice

Tags: miners, xmr-stak-amd

I recently (today) switched from wolf's xmr miner to xmr-stak-amd. First I would like to say that I'm getting a much better hashrate with the same settings (+100H/card) which I'm extremely happy about. However, I see on [github](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-amd) screen shots of an html report interface but I don't see any instructions for setting it up or running it. Is this a self contained webservice, does this need to be in a pubic directory, etc? I should also mention I'm running on Ubuntu 16.10.

Does anyone know how to access this / setup this web interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out for myself. The built in microhttp server runs when the port number is set in the config.txt file. Had I read all the way through the config file the first time I would have seen the comment at the end.